# How to switch static drivers like switching kernel module drivers?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have a linux embedded device that I need to switch between [USB file storage gadget driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/gadget/file_storage.c?v=2.6.37) and [USB Ethernet gadget driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/gadget/ether.c?v=2.6.37) at runtime.

The approach I use now is to build both drivers into kernel modules and switch the modules on demand.

If I build those two drivers statically into the kernel, is there still a way to disable one driver, release the hardware, and enable another driver, at run time?

Comment: If the former approach is working, why do you want to use the latter?

Comment: @FaheemMitha One difficulty is it's some extra effort to deploy updates when a header in the kernel is changed. If drivers are modules then I need to track and distribute all affected modules when a header is modified. However if drivers are built statically then I only need to distribute the uImage.